# How do I remove the info button and arrow in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableView in iOS and I want to remove the info button (i in a circle) and arrow (>) that are on the right hand side of each cell. How can I do so?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewCell has an [`accessoryType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryType) property. It can can be used programmatically like this. Keep in mind that you should [register your cell classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass%3aforCellReuseIdentifier%3a) with your table view so that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` doesn’t return nil (iOS 6+ only).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
    return cell;
}
```

The types are as follows:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,
    UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,
    UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,
    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark,
    UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

if you don’t want To use any, just remove this line:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
```

Or, if you have some cells that have an accessory and some that don’t,

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

This the "Detail Disclosure" accessory for the UITableViewCell. You can disable it in the Table View Cell Attributes section in the Storyboard Editor.